# On iOS 15 sims using Xcode 13, UITableView scrolltorowatindexpath:atScrollPosition:animated: results in the cell displaying beneath the section header

Tags: uitableview, ios15

On iOS 15.0 sims using Xcode 13.0, UITableView scrolltorowatindexpath:atScrollPosition:animated: results in the scrolled-to cell displaying partially beneath the section header (when UITableView.appearance() has previously been globally set to have a sectionHeaderTopPadding of 0.0).

So then I added it on the UITableView instance also, like `[myTableView setSectionHeaderTopPadding:0.0];` but now the table scrolls to the cell after the index path that was specified, and not only its section header but half of the next section header appear at the top, sandwiched together.

Why did Apple break tables and scrolling in iOS 15.0?

What is a workaround for this? Scrolling should work the same as before. Why are they issuing breaking changes in tables instead of making the changes opt-in? So freakin' annoying.